# Android Calendar Check Permission

Tags: android, permissions, calendar, securityexception

I'm currently implementing the calendar provider however i've stumbled upon a minor error that i'd like to prevent.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

....

Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, contentValues); // Error pops here
```

"Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException"

What is the best method to prevent this error?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle android permission first , check if they are available , if not you can request them as shown below

proceed with your functionality only if permissions are available

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);}else if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);}
```

Comment: This is correct, but OP should be aware that he needs to ask for READ_CALENDAR and WRITE_CALENDAR permission. Otherwise he will make a non user-friendly app. OP, you can check the complete doc here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: agreed with @andrei_zaitcev

Answer (score 0):

You can always add **throws SecurityException** to the method and take care of the caught exception further upstream.  Furthermore, I would recommend using this library https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions if you interested in using reactivex methodology to deal with permissioning.

Answer (score -2):

Your targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, just reduce it

Comment: You should properly handle permissions in newer versions of android

Comment: 6.0 is not popular, we don't force to use api 23, at least for now.

Comment: According to android dashboards 18.7% of android devices are running marshmallow, you definitely should  consider handling permissions on marshmallow and above, you risk losing a large portion of your user base because you deem it "not popular"