# how to fix need permission CALENDAR_READ or CALENDAR_WRITE?

Tags: java, android

Code shows

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening
>   provider com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2 from
>   ProcessRecord{ad38a2a 30100:com.example.myapplication/u0a231}
>   (pid=30100, uid=10231) requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR or
>   android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR

This is timeline calendar view who shows calendar in linear view with zooming

manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    calstuff.LoadCalendars();
    Log.d(LogTag, "calendars loaded: " + calstuff.ourCalendars.size());

    calstuff.LoadEvents();
    Log.d(LogTag, "events loaded: " + calstuff.ourEvents.size());
```

CalStuff.java

```
     Cursor calCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, 
     projection, Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1",
            null, Calendars._ID + " ASC");
```

i expect to display linear calendar time line ,  calendar can zoom by year -months-weeks-days but it shows me error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android permission doesn't work even if I have declared it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android permissions READ\_CALENDAR & WRITE\_CALENDAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110754/android-permissions-read-calendar-write-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

you need run time permission like below:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
   {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 
MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
    }
```

i coppied from below link:

[Android Calendar Check Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40236169/android-calendar-check-permission)

for more info read below link:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting